# How can I add the name of a contact to my table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Hey so I have a table view with 5 cells and whenever one of them is selected, a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController pops up and the user can select a contact. How can I make it so that the selected contact's name becomes the text of the cell's label? I've scoured the internet for about 2 hours now and I can't figure anything out for the life of me. :( Closest thing I found used an array to store multiple contacts in dynamic cells but I have static cells... Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.
Here's what I have so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {

        let multiValue: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()
        let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier)
        let contactInfo = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

        let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String

    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {

        peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker, didSelectPerson: person, property: property, identifier: identifier)

        peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        return false;
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
        peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: So am I right to say that upon selecting a contact, you want the cell in your main view controller to reflect `firstName`?

Comment: Yup! How would I go about doing this? Would you mind showing me an example? @Sudeep Anything would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, create a reference to the selected row.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Create a property for the selected cell, and set it when the row is selected
    self.selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When the contact is selected in the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, set the text of the selected cell to `firstName`.

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {

    peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker, didSelectPerson: person, property: property, identifier: identifier)

    let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String

    // Set the text of the selected cell
    self.selectedCell.textLabel.text = firstName

    // You might have to reload the tableView data on completion to reflect the change
    peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    return false;
}
```

Also, I believe `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:` has been deprecated since iOS 8.0, so you should be using just `didSelectPerson:` instead if you are targeting 8.0 and above.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate/peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:) for reference.

Comment: Also, apologies if there are any errors with the code. I am more fluent in Objective C.